Flutter exception handling with type conversions in go_router_builder
In a web application using go_router and go_router_builder I would like to handle exceptions gracefully when a path-parameter cannot be converted (for example using 2a for an int parameter).
I am using this example as a base:
https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router_builder/example/lib/shell_route_with_keys_example.dart
Using the route '/#/users/2a' an exception is produced, but neither onException, errorBuilder or errorPageBuilder is called if added to the _router object.
Is it possible to handle these exceptions?

I will show you how I use the builder param. It will not answer your question, but it may help you:
GoRoute(
  path: 'detail',
  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    final content = state.extra;
    if (content is DetailScreenContent) { // validating that `content` is object of a wanted type, in my case  `DetailScreenContent`
      return DetailScreen(
      content: content,
      );
    } else {
      // handling exception if `content` is anything else than my wanted type `DetailScreenContent`
    }
  },
  redirect: (context, state) {
    if (state.extra == null) return '/'; // handling in `redirect` is possible also
    return null;
  },
)


sorry, but this isn't even using go_router_builder...
